# Query de update com select para Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Estou tentando fazer uma query que vai entrar em uma procedure porém não estou tendo sucesso, a query esta assim:

```
UPDATE 
  sca_lotacao AS t0 
SET 
  t0.ativo = 0 
WHERE (
    SELECT * 
    FROM 
      sca_pessoa AS t1
      RIGHT JOIN sca_lotacao AS t2 ON t1.idLotacao = t2.idLotacao
    WHERE 
      t1.matricula IS NULL);
```

Erro:

```
Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Eu sei que realmente deve ter algo errado, mas estou tentando resolver isso.
No SELECT eu faço para que seja feito a seleção de todos os campos da Lotação que não tenha matrícula e atribuir a eles o valor de 0 (inativo), mas não sei se essa lógica está muito bem.

Pelo que vejo até consigo trazer todas as lotações que não tem ninguém.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o seu intuito é atualizar todos os campos onde existam registros que atendam a tal condição, você deve usar o operador `EXISTS`

```
UPDATE 
  sca_lotacao AS t0 
SET 
  t0.ativo = 0 
WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * 
    FROM sca_pessoa AS t1 
    WHERE t1.idLotacao = t0.idLotacao);
```

Comment: Esse número 1 no ... EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM..   está certo mesmo? Bem de qualquer forma estou com esse erro agora: 
You can't specify target table 't0' for update in FROM clause

Comment: @phpricardo o um é uma constante, já que o exists nao precisa trazer nenhum dado. Vou reverter para ter o JOIN no from. Há muito tempo não utilizava mySql para lembrar que ele não permite o uso do campo no WHERE do Update. Obrigado pelo feedBack

Comment: Hehe eu te ajudei a lembrar? Cara pq não precisa mais do JOIN ?

Comment: @phpricardo vou ter de trabalhar melhor no join, mas tenho q correr com algo aqui. Com o JOIN tb não está correto pq não está filtrando para cada registro da tabela a set atualizada. assim q tiver uma resposta posto aqui e te notifico.

Comment: Outro detalhe é que agora não está mais dando erro, mas da "no resulset"

Comment: Consegue resolver o problema!

UPDATE sca_lotacao AS t0 SET t0.ativo = 0 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sca_pessoa AS t1 WHERE t1.idLotacao = t0.idLotacao);

Comment: @phpricardo blz, vou atualizar com a sua query! vlw